# UIMoreNavigationController Frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've a problem with a UINavigationController in the UIMoreNavigationController.

In the UITabBar if the UINavigationController's View is on a Icon in the TabBar it all works fine. But If I access the View in the UIMoreNavigationController there the View begins 44px too high, so the View starts behind the UINavigationBar of the UIMoreNavigationController.

In the Root UIVIewController of the UINavigationController I've set the frame:
myViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480-20-44-49);

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are doing and what classes are involved. Does `UIMoreNavigationController` subclass `UINavigationController`? If so the docs say that it is not intended for subclassing. Also if it is your own subclass you should probably not include the `UI` prefix as it makes it sound like it is part of the cocoa touch framework perhaps your own prefix would be better

Comment: The UIMoreNavigationController is a Part of the UITabBarController, what is generated automatically when there are more then 5 Controllers on the TabBar, so I haven't subclassed the UIMoreNavigationController!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. There is no such thing as 'UIMoreNavigationController' the is a property called 'moreNavigationController' that holds a reference to a 'UINavigationController'. Can I ask why you are settings the frame in your rootViewController? When you add the view controller to navigation controller it should resize appropriately

Comment: If I do not, I've about 20 px space under the navigation bar, and then the View is continuing under the TabBar.

Comment: Can we see the code where you construct the tabbar with navigation controller?

Comment: I did it in the Interface Builder, I began the App long time ago, there I wasn't able to do it via code :)
But I've seen if i do all programmaticaly, It works. So I make a new App, with the new ARC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an iOS Bug, resolved with a newer Version.